# Ways to share data between desktop application and mobile app

Tags: database, mobile, cloud, endpoint, datastore

I want certain data from a iot endpoint or desktop implementation of app to be seen on mobile version of an app and visa versa.  All endpoints should be able to access and change data as they see fit.

What are the ways that you can make data available to all endpoints?  For instance I have a list of tasks that i make on the application on my desktop.  Then I leave my house turn off my desktop and pull up the mobile version of the application.  I want to see that same list.  What are the ways to do this?  I have considered a cloud hosted database but it kinda seems like overkill to have a database to store maybe 10kb of data as well as the cost associated with using their service.

Things I have considered but discarded because they dont fit-

google drive with a shareable googlesheet

- The issue is that it is read only. Also speed and functionality is limited.

database running on desktop that syncs to mobile app.

- The issue is that mobile app needs to be running at same time as desktop. also any changes the mobile makes to the data will not be saved to database if desktop version is not on.

Is there a way to do this without having a personal server running all the time to serve out data?  Is there any database hosting that is free?  Or is there something more lightweight than a database that would allow me to access and modify the data from any endpoint that has internet?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on many factors so a little hard to give you the "This is clearly the best option" answer.

Easiest? Probably kick up a hosted database in a Cloud provider. I'm partial to Firebase/Firestore (Google) for mobile. They're extremely low latency, so any changes are reflected pretty much instantly, and they have an awesome SDK that makes it really easy to get up and running quickly. It's equally as easy on mobile and desktop. It does require a Google Cloud Platform account to use it, but the free tiers are super generous, so unless you're doing a ton of updating, it's probably free to host it (and you get $300 free credits for the first year of GCP).

https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: Firebase is an relational db? Does it use classic SQL queries?

Comment: It's a NoSQL document-based db. It doesn't use classic SQL queries, no. It has its own querying API that's very straightforward. Check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?authuser=0 for example on reading data from the database.